# ACF multiple empty fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, is-empty

I have two fields set for ACF posts specific to a custom post type.

`edition_number` and `artist_proofs`

Some post types dont have any data set for these, while some post types do. I am putting this function in the content-single.php template so that if it does have that info, it should pass.

For some reason, this is still returning 'Edition of' even though a post I have does not have anything in both those fields.

```
function ffm_edition() {  
    if ( get_field( 'edition_number' ) && get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) { 
        echo 'Edition of ' , the_field( 'edition_number' ) , ', ' , the_field( 'artist_proofs' ) , 'APs';
    } elseif ( empty( get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) ) {
        echo 'Edition of ' , the_field( 'edition_number' );
    } elseif ( empty( get_field( 'edition_number' ) && get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) ) {
        //DO NOTHING
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was a simple contextual error…

The second check is just checking if the `artist_proofs` field is empty. Since both are empty, it will then return `edition of` always. I needed to make a check for a valid string + a null string:

```
} elseif ( get_field( 'edition_number' ) && empty( get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) ) {
```

full snippet:

```
function ffm_edition() {  
  if ( get_field( 'edition_number' ) && get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) { 
      echo 'Edition of ' , the_field( 'edition_number' ) , ' + ' , the_field( 'artist_proofs' ) , 'APs';
  } elseif ( get_field( 'edition_number' ) && empty( get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) ) {
      echo 'Edition of ' , the_field( 'edition_number' );
  } elseif ( empty( get_field( 'edition_number' ) ) && empty( get_field( 'artist_proofs' ) ) ) {
    //DO NOTHING
  }
}
```